# How can I add the new “Button” at the edge of side nav

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

what is the best way to put the button at the edge of sidenav?

For instance this pink button:

[image]

In the above exemple, this button is perfectly placed between two layout

similarly i want to add "cancel" button at the edge of sidenav in my webpage

[image]

I am using angular-material with flex box.

HTML:

```
<mat-sidenav-container fxLayout="column">
  <div fxLayout="column" >
    <div fxFlex="grow">        
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button class="vertposition" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
      </button>
     <float-button icon="add" direction="top" class="addButtonPosition">
        <float-item-button icon="person_add" content="float item 1"></float-item-button>
        <float-item-button icon="gps_fixed" content="float item 2"></float-item-button>
        <float-item-button icon="mode_edit" content="float item 3"></float-item-button>
    </float-button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="mainContentContainer">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="over">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

CSS:

```
.mat-drawer-container {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0);
}
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100vh;
}
.mainContentContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.vertposition{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.addButtonPosition{
  top: auto !important;
  right: 20px !important;
  bottom: 10px !important;
  left: auto !important;
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

I am trying to replace the following button with floating action button and place it on sidenav's edge

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
  <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: If you can share the relevant code (HTML and CSS) we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Please post your component code and your component HTML code. Also take note that the "pink button" is known as a Floating Action Button, or FAB for short

Comment: thanks for looking in to this. updated my question with HTML and CSS

Comment: Were you able to find a fix to your issue?

Comment: tried but did not got the solution

Comment: Anyone able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this problem with css, I show you a drawer what comes from the right side with a button on the edge.

my example:

html:

```
<mat-drawer-container autosize>
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" position="end">
    <button class="drawer-close-button">X</button>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
  </mat-drawer>
  <span>content</span>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

css:

```
.drawer-close-button{
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
}
 ::ng-deep .mat-drawer {
  overflow: visible
}
```